# flask not found in Docker

Tags: docker

In the Docker file, I get this error
ImportError: No module named flask

Here is the Docker file

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
MAINTAINER kumar
COPY ./flask_master /usr/local/python
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /usr/local/python
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD python flaskPredictAPI.py
```

Here is the requirements.txt

```
flask
flasgger
joblib
```

But when I run it, I get this

```
docker run -i -t -p 5000:5000 randomforestapi
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskPredictAPI.py", line 1, in 
    from flask import Flask, request
ImportError: No module named flask

Comment: Have u verified  installation? Check docker logs.

Comment: docker logs 0ee8a1961f61
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskPredictAPI.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request
ImportError: No module named flask

Comment: I changed it to python3 , but still the same result

Comment: The last line in your Dockerfile, try python3 instead of python

Comment: run image in bash session, check flask installation. docker run -it {imageId} /bin/bash and this ^^

Comment: docker build had errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to build your docker image successfully? Did you checked if during build the requirements.txt gets executed without any error? I would suggest you generate your requirements.txt using below command in your project folder.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It would look something like this

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```